# UK: Looking to plot house/building numbers on a map, but can't find a data source

Tags: united-kingdom, ordnance-survey, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to plot UK house numbers on a map but I'm having trouble finding a good data source.

I have download the Ordnance Survey Master Map and the CartographicText layer does contain some house numbers, but nowhere near all of them. I also did a histogram analysis of the data provided, and given the number "12" is more popular than the number "3" and "4" I don't think this can be trusted.

I've also looked into using the Google reverse geocoding API as I have accurate lat/longs for each building, but the results provided are not accurate enough. For example I live at house number 7, but reverse geocoding my position when at home returns house number 5.

Is there any dataset or API which provides accurate house and building numbers for the UK based on a lat/long for a building?

Comment: `given the number "12" is more popular than the number "2" I don't think this can be trusted` it raises an interesting question of what the most common house number integer should be.

Comment: @nmtoken I made a quick graph showing the frequency in my dataset: http://jsfiddle.net/8tkexw2r/2/ P.S. I was incorrect originally, 12 is more common than 3 and 4 but not 2. Intuitively you would think lower numbers would be more popular than higher numbers which is why I don't think it can be trusted.

Comment: Intuition can be a dangerous thing though...  Rather than dismissing the result as obviously wrong (it could be, I don't know) you might ask the question could it be correct? so what if lower numbers are more likely to be flats 2a, 2b.. or have house names??

Comment: @nmtoken I see where you're coming from but this isn't the only suspicious thing about this dataset. When plotting it on a map it's clear that it only has house numbers for approximately 1/10th of houses.

Comment: Royal Mail Postal Address File >PAF > https://www.poweredbypaf.com/product/paf/ 30m+
UK postal delivery addresses **Expensive Dataset**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive resource is [Ordnance Survey Addressbase](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/addressbase-support). The basic product is the geocoded Royal Mail Postal Address File. The Plus product additionally contains data sourced from local authorities (primarily alternative names and non postal objects and so of less use to you) and finally the Premium product also contains historic and planned addresses.

CartographicText is a poor resource for property numbers. In addition to the omissions its revision is not kept in sync with AddressBase and to my knowledge is only revisited when there is cause to re-survey the location leading to many legacy names and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The **National Receptor Dataset (NRD)** may have the data you need.  This is a point type feature class with national coverage which contains a number of fields that might be of relevance to you, most notably the 'bldgnumber' field.  This is not a freely-available dataset, however I note that you have access to OS MasterMap so you may be able to gain access to the NRD through the same mechanism.  The NRD is based on OS AddressBase Premium that Tom mentions in their answer, so the NRD could be seen as an alternative if the former is unavailable.

Note that the NRD is a very comprehensive dataset that has points for many features beyond just residential properties (e.g. street records, telephone boxes), however there is information within it to allow you to only select residential properties (albeit there may be some instances where residential properties have not been classified as such).

Answer (score 0):

According this forum:

https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/5766920/uk-map-with-house-numbers

The best way is checking the Ordnance Survey maps with the largest scalle possible 1:1250 and check the house numerations, which is provided from time to time.

The one reasonable way to access these maps for free is the CityOfLondon map service available here:

https://www.mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/geocortex/mapping/?viewer=compass&runworkflowbyid=Switch_layer_themes&LayerTheme=Show%20the%20Explore%20The%20City%20layers

unfortunataly you can't do the Postcode or address search beyond the Greater London borders unless you do the anual search by zooming out and browsing the country.

[image]